# What's the exact value of the most negative 32-bit floating point number?

Tags: floating-point, min, ieee-754

I was wonder if there is an exact value of the most negative 32-bit floating point value (by IEEE-754 standard)?

I have seen two pixel values in two floating point TIFF files apparently targeting the the most negative 32-bit `float`:

```
-3.4028230607370965E38
-3.4028234663852886E38
```

which is correct? (Or, is the value language/platform specific.)

I searched Google, and get `-3.4E38` most of the time, which is approximate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer assumes that the `float` format is actually IEEE 754 binary32, which it definitely would be if it was used in the context of a file format such as TIFF. If an architecture used non-IEEE 754 floating-point internally, it would be this architecture's responsibility to handle the IEEE 754 binary32 numbers in TIFF images.

The exact value of the most negative floating-point number is, [in hexadecimal](http://www.exploringbinary.com/hexadecimal-floating-point-constants/), -0x1.fffffep127. It is slightly unpleasant to write in decimal because of the large number of digits it requires, so people usually write one of several decimal approximations that, when converted to `float`, produce this number. Neither of the two values in your question are the exact value of -0x1.fffffep127.

Note that “-3.4E38” is not an approximation that, when converted to float, produces the most negative float. It is just a rough ballpark.

The exact value of the most negative float, when written in decimal, is:

-3.4028234663852885981170418348451692544e+38

The first value in your question, as a candidate for the most negative `float` is very strange, because whoever wrote it bothered to write digits that are wrong, and indeed, it does not round to the most negative float:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
  printf("%.38e\n", -FLT_MAX);
  printf("%.38e\n", -0x1.fffffep127);
  printf("%.38e\n",-3.4028230607370965E38f);
  printf("%.38e\n\n",-3.4028234663852886E38f);
  printf("%a\n",-3.4028230607370965E38f);
}
```

Producing:

```
-3.40282346638528859811704183484516925440e+38
-3.40282346638528859811704183484516925440e+38
-3.40282306073709652508363335590014353408e+38
-3.40282346638528859811704183484516925440e+38

-0x1.fffffap+127
```

The above program requires a `printf` function that, when converting a `double` to decimal, prints all digits correctly. If this is not what you have, the program may produce a different result, but is should still show that there is a float more negative than the first float in your question.

It shows that the second value in your question is a decimal approximation of the most negative float (it rounds to the same value when parsed with the `f` suffix), whereas the first value is 2 [ULPs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) from the most negative float (-0x1.fffffcp+127 is one ULP from the most negative float, and -0x1.fffffap+127 is two ULPs away. There are only 23 explicit significand bits in the single-precision `float` format, and 23 is not a multiple of 4, hence the last bit in the 6-digit hexadecimal notation not being used).